# Circulation: calculation via line integral and Stokes' theorem

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

Find circulation of the vector field around the closed line $G$ as below by two ways: via line integral and by Stokes theorem.
The vector filed $F = [xy,xy,z]$
The closed line $G$ defined as: $x^2+z^2=1-y\quad\wedge\quad(x\geqslant 0\quad\wedge\quad y\geqslant 0\quad\wedge\quad z\geqslant 0)$,  ie the 1st octant.

So we have the infinite paraboloid bounded by the first octant to get the closed line $G$.
Also we have $C=\oint\limits_{\Gamma }{\mathbf{F}d\mathbf{l}}=\oint\limits_{\Gamma }{(F_{x}dx+F_{y}dy+F_{z}dz)}$.
The Stokes' theorem: $\oint\limits_{\Gamma }{\mathbf{F}d\mathbf{l}=\iint\limits_{S}{\operatorname{rot}}}\mathbf{F}\cdot \mathbf{n}dS$

However, I am not sure how to finilze the calculation.
By the way the sketch of the surface:
[image]

Comment: can you tell what the surface involved is? Have you sketched it? What do you think the boundary is?

Comment: @qbert I think that according to the problem the contour is cut from the paraboloid in the first octant: $x=0$, $y=0$, $z=0$, sorry, I did a mistake for the surface, corrected by now!